# Something has gone wrong even if the upgrade was successfully

Tags: gnome, upgrade, gdm, 21.10

There are tons of questions about this error but almost all of them refer to interrupted dist-upgrades. Instead, I've upgraded from 20.04 to 21.10 without any problem (at least, no popups that show errors).

The machine is headless and it's configured with a dummy monitor to be accessed by a remote desktop application:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I have a sort of SSH connection to the device, but when I try to enable the remote desktop I get the "Something has gone wrong" screen.

I tried almost all the solutions provided in the other threads, example:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt-get remove gnome-session gdm3 gnome gnome-shell
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo reboot
```

but none of them fixed the problem.

I checked `dmesg` output but I found only this error:

```
[   20.487647] gnome-shell[1144]: segfault at cc0800b8 ip 00007fea14214015 sp 00007ffe766e7cb0 error 4 in libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0[7fea14213000+4000]
```

as I read somewhere it should be there because I disabled Wayland.

Any hint about what I can check?

Comment: *I've upgraded from 20.04 to 21.10 without any problem* How did you do that? There is no supported upgrade path.

Comment: I did it on three machines without any issue. The `update-manager` GUI told me there was a newer version available and asked me if I want to upgrade. Then it did the dist upgrade.

Comment: Is there any further info I can provide to fix this issue? I'm stuck and I cannot recover the system.